# Windows "Fall Creators Update" breaks Store App on screen keyboard

Tags: c#, windows, xaml

All of the text boxes in my Windows 8.1 Store App do not reliably cause the on-screen keyboard to display when they are focused. Prior to the Windows 10 Fall Creators Update (Windows Version 1079) the text boxes worked great. The soft keyboard would always show when they were focused.

However, since the update the keyboard will only appear, seemingly, randomly. My question is, is this a Windows OS defect and I am out of luck until Microsoft publishes an update or am i missing something that will help indicate to the OS that I want the keyboard to show when the text box is focused?

Other details: Running windows version 1079, surface pro 3, the device is in tablet mode, no keyboard is connected.

Update: The app is intended to run in Single Application Mode. The user does not have access to the taskbar so they will be unable to manually display the keyboard.

Here is an example of my textbox in xaml.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding EmailAddress, Mode=TwoWay}"  
                                     PlaceholderText="noreply@example.com..."
                                     AutomationProperties.Name="Email Sender Address"
                                     x:Name="EmailTextBox"
                                     />
```

Comment: [Related link](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/surface/forum/surfpro4-surfdrivers/after-fall-creators-update-oct-2017-on-screen/fc801683-c382-49bd-98db-481987923aa1?auth=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After over a month of looking I finally found a Microsoft forum link which identifies this exact problem and Microsoft's response to the problem.

[MSDN Link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/b5e10bb9-d281-42b6-8900-489ffab4f7b5/windows-update-1709-tablet-mode-touch-keyboard-no-longer-automatically-pops-up-on-screen?forum=wpdevelop)

There is more detail in the link but here is a good quote from that thread

> "We’ve identified that your issue was indeed fixed in Insider Preview
>   build 17083 RS4.  We are working on identifying if there is a backward
>   patch that can be applied to 1709."

and a follow up post in the thread.

> "According to the development team, the issue doesn’t reproduce on
>   recent RS4 bits (where significant changes have been done around Touch
>   interaction).
>
> Have you tried to confirm this by yourself by installing latest
>   Windows Insider preview build which may contain the fix?
>
> Please note that the official release of RS4 is not yet known, but it
>   should happen during spring.
>
> The product group is actually reluctant to bring these changes to RS3
>   (aka Fall Creators Update or 1709)."

Unfortunately this also leaves me with two very unsatisfying answers....

1. Wait until Microsoft releases the next Windows update
2. Install the insider preview build (RS4, version 17083)

Neither of those are really a great option but I'm sort of at the mercy of Microsoft here.